# Simple double counting in a circular permutation problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

**Question:** In how many ways are there to arrange 6 boys and 8 girls (each of them are unique) on a round table ?

Clearly the answer is $13!$ by circular permutation.

But here’s another argument that I tried:
first arrange all the boys which means we arrange 6 boys on 14 place thus we have ${14 \choose 6} \cdot 6!$, but we know the places are arranged in a circular way, thus there are 14 identical case (by rotation), thus we divide it by 14.

Finally, all is left is to arrange the girls, for which there are $8!$ ways.

Hence the number of ways to arrange them are $\frac{{14 \choose 6} \cdot 6! \cdot 8!}{14}=13!$.

I know it is the same. But is my second argument valid, or its just a coincidence?

Comment: Yes, your argument is valid.

Comment: Your argument is valid, and you can also prove it algebraically if you wish. Note that 14C6 is equal to 14!/6!8! by definition, so multiplying it is bound to give 14!. I leave the more general proof to you.